# d3.js : how to access fill attribute of svg group element (stacked bar chart)

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js

newbie d3.js here, i'm trying to understand the sample of stacked bar chart using `d3.stack()` (**note :** not `d3.layout.stack()`) from the sample link : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 (by Mike Bostock)

I'm trying to access the fill attribute of each svg group elements which each represents a single 'layer' / age group. To do so, I do a little modification at the "enter" part :

```
var seriesG = g.selectAll(".serie") 
    .data(function(){return stackedColumns;})
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "serie")
      .attr("fill", function(d) {return z(d.key); });
```

Since `console.log(seriesG);` resulted in `zi {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}`, i figured that the seven svg group elements that represents the seven age range groups is accessible in the `_groups` member object.

Now, I can access each svg group element by this basic recursive routine :

```
seriesG._groups.forEach(function(d, i){
    console.log(d);
  });
```

which displays `[g, g, g, g, g, g, g]` in the browser element inspector console (opera). What I'm trying to figure out is the correct syntax to access the fill attribute of the 'd' datum. And since by observing the browser console I know that the 'fill' is the member of `'outerHTML'` member attribute of the 'd' datum, first I must know how to access this 'outerHTML' attribute. I have tried various syntax :

- `console.log(d.attr("outerHTML"));`
- `console.log(d.attr.outerHTML);`
- `console.log(d.outerHTML);`
- `console.log(d["outerHTML"]);`

The first two tries resulted in `Uncaught TypeError: d.attr is not a function`, while the remaining two are `undefined` operations.

So, in the short version of my question is : "What is the correct syntax to access the fill of each svg group element created using `d3.stack()`?"

My ultimate goal is to add various functionality similiar to this sample link : http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360

Comment: Your *d* object is an array, you have to perform a *forEach* on this array in order to access *g* element attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Mario Alexandro Santini,       `seriesG._groups.forEach(function(d, i){
 d.forEach(function(datum){
  console.log(datum);
 })
  });` successfully displays `<g class="serie" fill="#someHex">...</g>`, However, this is still half the way, my question remains unanswered : "what is the correct syntax to access the fill attribute?" `console.log(datum.attr("fill"));` resulted in `stackedBarChart.html:70 Uncaught TypeError: datum.attr is not a function` while both `console.log(datum.fill);` and `console.log(datum["fill"]);` are _undefined operations.

Comment: I suggest that you fix your question to clarify your objective. As it is, your question is about how to make your `._group` anti pattern do something that is not clear.

Comment: I think *.attr()* is a method of a *selection*, an element you get from d3 when you use the *selectAll()* or other selection methods. have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116909/selecting-path-within-g-element-and-change-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `_groups`.  This is meant to be *private* to the selection object.  You should be using the [.nodes method](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_nodes).

Second, my question is what do you want to do with those fills?

The code you are trying to write is this:

```
seriesG.nodes().forEach(function(d){
   console.log(d3.select(d).attr('fill'));
});
```

But, depending on the purpose, and since you know your keys (in the example you link to these are "65 Years and Over", "45 to 64 Years", etc..), then the fill value for any "key" can simply be returned as:

```
z("65 Years and Over");
```

Comment: What I want to do with the group fills : I want that when user click on a certain 'legend' rectangle, the age bar group with the same fill stays visible, while the bar group with the different fill will be set to 'opacity:0', similiar function with [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360). I want to, however, to achieve that same functionality by matching the 'fill' attribute of the clicked legend rect to the 'fill' of the age range bar group, which is a different approach compared to the sample link.

Comment: And to do so, I believe first I must be able to extract the 'fill' attribute of the age range bar group. Please correct me if you think this approach is wrong, I'm a newbie after all.

Comment: copy and paste your answer, it is not working.     `seriesG.nodes().forEach(function(){
   console.log(d3.select(this).attr('fill'));
});` will give this message on Opera :  `d3.v4.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: r.getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: @Rickard, typoed my answer before, see corrected code snippet above.   There is many ways to do what you are after with your legend click.  I would probably use d3's data-bindiing.  Bind a unique key to each legend rect.  Assign the corresponding series that key as a class.  On click retrieve the key, use a class selector to select the corresponding line and set it's opacity.  It's pretty late where I am I see if I can code up an example tomorrow morning.

Comment: thank you for your helpful replies, i think that the data binding approach is the one that is being used at the [sample link](http://bl.ocks.org/KatiRG/f7d064cd9c3efbc3c360), please correct me if i'm wrong. I'm trying to solve this with a different approach, that is by matching colors (which, from your replies,  I suppose you already understand what i'm trying to attempt). Well, if I cannot get the fill attribute from the age range bar group (because I cannot figure the proper syntax), then I'll just have to try the data binding approach instead.

Comment: @Rickard, here's a quick [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/h0qfZQcUGV7kTAUx1xDq?p=preview) with your approach.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the example, @Mark, I'll try to integrate your idea into my coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getAttribute()`

This way : `element.getAttribute('fill')`

More informations here :https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute